# Can I specify Availability Zone when creating Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I create an Elastic Beanstalk Instance (tomcat) , and it keeps getting created in eu-west-1a. The trouble is that  I can deploy the the war file okay but it also requires data files that were created on a different EC2 instance in eu-west-1b.

My idea was to copy the data to an ECB Volume. then detach that volume from that EC2 instance and then reattach to the EC2 instance used by my Elastic Beanstalk Instance. But you cannot move ECB Volumes from **1a** to **1b**

So is there an option I missed to specify Availability Zone when creating Elastic Beanstalk
Instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can specify in which AZs or Subnets you want your EB environments, but copying data and detaching - attaching volumes will have several issues. It may be a better idea to have a shared network filesystem that your application servers can mount. Another idea would be to use rsync to sync data between instances. This volume reattachment is probably complex, error prone and not scalable.

Comment: As you gave me the indication it could be done I found what I needed to do, 'select Create this environment inside a VPC', this is my first foray into AWS and I'm just trying to get something working for now, will fine tune later - I was thinking about using S3 bucket to transfer data, Im unclear how network fileystem fits into AWS

Comment: seems I should have heeded your advice about detached volumes, the volume now hangs trying to reattach to the original server, in fact any volume now hangs trying to attach to original server so I have had to create a new server instance.